# Pushing array into array then handling elements inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

so I just came across this, but could anyone explain it to me, why is this phenomenon present here? I didn't find any help online...

1.So if I were to get the following two arrays:

```
let a = [];
let b = ['','',''];
```

2.and then push array `b` into array `a` three times:

```
a.push(b);
a.push(b);
a.push(b);
```

3.but then when I try to change the first element of the first array like so:

```
a[0][0] = 'foo';
```

4.then all the first element of ALL the arrays change, not just the first one, as `console.log(a)` outputs:

```
(3) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: Array(3)
  0: "foo"
  1: ""
  2: ""

1: Array(3)
  0: "foo"
  1: ""
  2: ""

2: Array(3)
  0: "foo"
  1: ""
  2: ""
```

I would like to ask, why does this happen and in what way could I change an element based on its index inside of array `a`

Comment: The indices in `a` are all holding a *reference* to `b` -- "they all get updated" is a bit misleading, you're updating one object and it appears in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing `b` which is just a reference to an object. To have the behavior you want, change your code to be like this:

```
a.push(b.map((x) => x))
```

For more [see this page](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/).

Answer (score 2):

b is a pointer to a mutable array, changing the array it points to will cause the other places you point to it to update as well.

You would either push copies of b into the array or create a modified copy of b when trying to mutate the value it points to.

Answer (score 1):

if you `console.log(b)`, you'll see that as well.
Try doing `b[1] = "test"` then check the value of `a` and you'll see all the `b`'s that were pushed into there have `test` in them too.
`b` is a reference so anytime you change the value of it, you are altering the places it is referenced to.